Equalizer circuit using low pass filter
I'm working on my circuit theory project. My goal is to make a simple 3-channel equalizer using 1 low pass filter and 2 band pass filter.

Here is my circuit. Problem is, the 8kHz passive low pass filter(R12-C3 circuit) where I'm putting the input voltage seems to not work well when I connect the whole part. If I just simulate the lpf, it correctly prints out the 3dB frequency 8kHz. But if I connect with the rest part of the circuit, output of the LPF is just a low dB version of the whole output-sum of the results of the 2 bpfs! Here's the simulation result of LPF when connected, and output voltage of the whole circuit.


Why is this happening? How can I modify this circuit to achieve my goal? Also, it would be grateful for me to notify some minor problems with this circuit.

When designing low pass filters, use LC filters instead of RC filters. LC filters are power efficient.

I'll try. Will it work? But why does RC filter result is not what I was expecting when connected?

I think you have a power supply issue with one of the Opamps. a +voltage goes to a negative supply pin and vice versa. It's impossible to see what it's called, the schematic is so crowded.

The middle one by R15. Seriously, i would implore you to clean up that schematic. A few hints: You don't /need/ a separate power supply for each opamp, they can all share the same two voltage sources. The net name tool is your friend.

oh, actually - that goes for U1 as well. +15V is wired to the - supply pin and -15V is wired to the + supply pin.

After a very quick look, I think you need a x1 buffer after the LPF: have you considered that your other filters want a near-zero ohm source resistance?

The schematic is crowded. Be generous and  make it bigger and spacious so that its easy to understand.

I guess since I am not used to the LTSpice yet, I haven't think about marking the Vcc and Vee, even though I myself thought my schematic is hard to understand because all of those power supplies for Op Amp. Thanks everyone for such advice(This is my first question, and I didn't expect so many kind people will look on my circuit and help me!), I will work on the power of the op amps first. I'll look for buffers as well.

The main problem is that some of the supplies are not connected properly, you have flipped some of the opamps upside down, probably to get the inputs with + or - on the top, but then didn't account for this when connecting the supply voltages.
I would suggest trying to keep all of the opamp symbols the same, with the positive supply at the top. Consistency can help avoid errors.
You have also used a separate set of supplies for each opamp, which makes the schematic crowded and hard to read, makes it more error prone as you can see with the polarities being wrong, and is unnecessary, you wouldn't have different supplies for each opamp in a real circuit.
A better way to do the supplies is like in this example circuit:

Here there is a single set of supplies for all the opamps, as would be done in hardware, and just the labels are shown connected to the opamps so there aren't any voltage sources taking up room or wires going all over the place, it's much cleaner, easier to read, and easier to troubleshoot.
You can call the labels whatever you want, Vcc and Vee are common for bipolar supplies, you could use +15V and -15V, Vdd and Vss for MOSFET based circuits, or basically any short name you want.
There is some debate about how the negative voltage source is done in LTspice, some people ground the - of each source and change the polarity of the negative source as shown in METHOD 1 below, some people will make the negative supply a positive voltage and flip the connections as shown in METHOD 2, still others stack the supplies and put ground in the middle as shown in METHOD 3. All will work, I prefer METHOD 1 or METHOD 3 myself.

Redraw the schematic using these suggestions and you'll probably find that it works as expected, if not it will at least be easier to find any other problems.

I now completely and rigorously avoid all three of the methods at bottom. Instead I use cards. V999 Vcc 0 6 followed by V998 Vee 0 -6' (or V998 0 Vee 6', which has also come from me sometimes.) But I've grown to prefer removing as much graphical and wiring dross as I possibly can from a schematic. It just adds "noise" and serves no purpose at all in understanding the schematic subsections and/or how they relate.

This is probably a good example from some years ago.

I guess since I am not used to the LTSpice yet, I haven't think about marking the Vcc and Vee, even though I myself thought my schematic is hard to understand because all of those power supplies for Op Amp. Thanks everyone for such advice(This is my first question, and I didn't expect so many kind people will look on my circuit and help me!), I will work on the power of the op amps first.
